# What is the question mark?

Tags: number-sequence

My friend gave me this sequence of numbers：

---

3=11

---

6=12

---

11=13

---

14=14

---

361114=A

---

A=?

---

Which number can replace the question mark?

Comment: This is the original!

Comment: Does A change the answer?

Comment: A It doesn't make any sense

Comment: Could the last two lines have been replaced with `361114=?` instead of adding a variable into the mix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Solution:**

> 10. A (hexadecimal) = 10

Another possible Solution could be:

> 1. Since A is the first letter in the alphabet

If it's

> 11121314

then it's too easy.

Comment: A is just a medium for transformation!

Comment: I'm thinking the last one here is the most applicable, and probably the answer to the question. Can you confirm/deny @Tanton?

Comment: I'm also inclined to this answer！

Comment: @Tanton you don't know the answer?

Comment: Yes, I really don't know.

Comment: @Tanton maybe you should discuss this with your friend before you accept this answer

Comment: I agree with Adam.

Comment: I don't think any of those are correct. First of all, we know that A was meant to just be a placeholder and it could have been any letter so your first two solutions are out. For the last one, math doesn't work that way :D Your final solution actually gave me an idea of what it could have been, and I wrote an answer with that. Great work, anyways!

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath the last one was my first proposed answer after which the OP edited his post to include A. Which got me thinking it was somehow important, forcing me to justify a reason for A's inclusion. Hence me later two answers (Moved to the top).

Comment: @Abbas - Ohh, interesting...

Comment: This answer currently says that "A (hexadecimal) = 11" but in hexadecimal A means 10. No part of it has any actual explanation that I can make any sense of it. @Tanton I really don't think this should be accepted.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan you're right. fixedt it.

Comment: I literally cannot understand what you're saying with this answer. Both "new" and "another possible" solutions ignore the entirety of the puzzle save its final entry and focus on the letter, whose specific inclusion may indeed be relevant somehow but certainly shouldn't be the be-all-end-all of the puzzle. This is supposed to be a sequence of numbers; you've discarded the sequence entirely and just proposed a substitution of number for variable. How is this a solution to the sequence? @Tanton how is this possibly a satisfying answer?

Answer (score 7):

I also have a solution

> **123468**

because,

> Think of the number to the left of the sequence as octal

Like

> 3（octal）= 11（binary）
>  6（octal）= 12（quanternary）
>  11（octal）= 13（Senary）
>  14（octal）= 14（octal）

So

> **361114（octal）= 123468（decimal）**

Comment: My answer is based on the fact that A has no effect. Because A=123468 is substituted into the next formula, I can't continue to convert.

Comment: What determines the bases used on the right-hand sides?

Comment: On the right hand side is a series of even numbers, and adds 2.I think it's a rule.

Answer (score 4):

An alternate solution is:

> 24024

because,

> generally, when you have variable names next to each other (e.g. $xy$) that would mean that you are multiplying their values (e.g. $x\times y$).

Therefore,

> you would multiply $11\times12\times13\times14=24024$

Comment: Also a valid theory, It could be your answer is the one OP's friend was looking for!

Comment: How does this account for things like "11=13" in the question?

Comment: Maybe I'm just slow today... why did you select those numbers to multiply?

Comment: I don't think multipliers can be omitted between numbers. One example is 6÷2 (1 + 2).

Comment: @sypicky - That's true, but neither can you say $3=11$... This is assuming the numbers on the left are variables.

Comment: @sypicky - The numbers on the left _must_ be variables because they are set to different values than what they actually are.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - I'm not sure I understand. It should be perfectly clear (and fairly obvious IMO)...

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath your assumption is that the numbers should be treated like variables right? So 11=13 could be 11=1x(11) as 3 is already defined: 3=11. Even then it is also possible that since 3=11 and 11=13, 3=13. Oh and you cannot argue that only the left hand side is a variable since 361114=A (361114=?). By your own logic it would be logical to assume that "361114" is only one variable, substituting other variables defies the pattern. The last line also hasn't been cleared up yet so the variable "A" exists on both sides. No matter how you look at this it is unrealistic unfortunately

Comment: @Adam - Correct, but the question is fairly unrealistic, as well...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the last but one line, A is

> 361114

Comment: Well if A is this number then why is 3=11 or 6=12 or 11=13?

Comment: As, I have just seen Voldermort's 1st comment to the OP and up-voted it.